# Palindrome with array Javascript in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, css, reactjs

I'm working with an array of javascript on Palindrome.

My **array (input)**:

```
   const data = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Sub A', img: 'A.jpg'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Sub B', img: 'B.jpg'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Sub C', img: 'C.jpg'},
    {id: 4, title: 'Sub D', img: 'D.jpg'}
   ]
```

I want to output as:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uILcd.jpg)

My **code (buggy code)**:

```
  {
    data.map((item, index) => {
      const col = item.col ? item.col : '6';
      return (
          <div className={'col-md-' + col} key={index}>
            <div className={styles.servicesItem}>
              <a>
                { index === data[index - 1] ? '' : <img src={item.img} /> }
              </a>
              <span>{item.title}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    })
  }
```

Anyone have any way to format output as that?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does your output look like now? Can you post an example on codepen? Also, this seems more like a css question than javascript, may want to add that tag

Comment: I want to output: [My output image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uILcd.jpg)